# Looking for a type of the screw with very narrow end

Tags: fasteners

I'm looking for a type of screw like this:

[image]

but with even smaller diameter (pin size) smooth end. Preferably M6 thread and less than 2mm diameter end, preferably smooth. If specific part recommendations are not allowed on this forum, just a general clue of where to find something like this would be appreciated.

Comment: The diameter ratio for this type of nose on a set screw (grub screw) typically has only one choice, so 2mm nose on M6 might not be a common part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a dog point grub screw and you may be able to find your desired object at [McMaster-Carr](https://www.mcmaster.com/products/grub-screws/). The site has a selector panel and one of the entries in the panel includes the ability to specify the tip diameter. Notice also that tip length is in the selector panel. Image from linked site:

[image: McMaster-Carr selector panel]

Comment: He might be looking for a needle valve screw.

Comment: @PhilSweet, I suppose that's possible, but the image attached to the question is the dog point grub screw.

Comment: @PhilSweet Needle valve adjusting screw is indeed closer to what I was looking for, except that the size choice is very limited and specific to each valve model.